# How to auto-refresh a wordpress page at a specific time of day

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I'd like to have my wordpress homepage refresh at a specific time each day, at 8:59pm.  I'm semi-familiar with CSS and HTML, but know next to nothing about Javascript, so if you could explain solutions in-detail, that'd be really helpful.

The specific use-case is that I'm embedding a scheduled Facebook live stream, which requires a refresh if users have already loaded the site before the stream goes live.  Our show starts at 9pm and the stream goes live at 8:59, so if we could force an auto-refresh at 8:59, we could ensure nobody misses the stream (our audience is mostly  comprised of older folks that aren't very tech-savvy).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

```
 setInterval(function(){
  const date = new Date();

  const hour = date.getHours();
  const minute = date.getMinutes();

  console.log(hour, minute);

  if(hour == 8 && minute == 59){
    location.reload();
  }
},1000);
```

> Returns the hour in the specified date according to local time.
>   If UTC is desired, use new Date(Date.UTC(...)) with the same
>   arguments.

Comment: We should point out that the above is at 8:59 (LOCAL TIME). This means 8:59 on the viewing user's clock. If your viewers are in different time zones it will not work as expected.

Comment: not sure its a problem in this instance but time zones hurt... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Thanks, this is close to what I need, but I'd like it to be functional across different time zones.  Also, apologies for the lack of knowledge, but where would a piece of code like this go, specifically?

Answer (score 0):

```
function refreshAt(hours, minutes, seconds) 
{
    var now = new Date();
    var then = new Date();

    if ( now.getHours() > hours || (now.getHours() == hours && 
 now.getMinutes() > minutes) || now.getHours() == hours && 
now.getMinutes() == minutes && now.getSeconds() >= seconds ) 
    {
        then.setDate(now.getDate() + 1);
    }
    then.setHours(hours);
    then.setMinutes(minutes);
    then.setSeconds(seconds);

    var timeout = (then.getTime() - now.getTime());
    setTimeout(function() { window.location.reload(true); }, timeout);
}
```

To run this function use,

```
refreshAt(18,45,0); //Will refresh the page at 18:45pm
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  So just to clarify, the first block of code goes in functions.php, right?  And then the second can go in any theme file, such as Single Page (page.php) or Single Post (single.php)?

Comment: just tried doing the above, WP doesn't like the fact that (hours, minutes, seconds) is declared in the first line.  Getting error: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)